# Suplotting all the columns in my dataframe with a format

Tags: python

I am inputting some numbers into a list using loop and want to make sure that the list in question has 5 elements but also ensure that there is no duplicate.
I have a problem with my ensuring part, as that part still allows duplicate into my list. How do I really make sure that this problem is dealt with. Something like keeping the question **i** as long as I do not have 5 elements in the list but also ensuring that I do not have any duplicates. 
 Here is my code. Feel free to improve it as well if you want to.

```
numbers=[]

for i in range(1,6):
    numb=int(input('Please enter your number: '))
    if numb in numbers:
       print ('This number has already been choosen ')
       numbers.remove(numb)
    else:
      numbers.append(numb)

#ensuring part        
if len(numbers)<5:
   again=5-len(numbers)
   for i in range(again):
       num=int(input('Enter another numb: '))
       numbers.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensure you don't have duplicates (values (without checking it by yourself) replace the *list* with a *set*.
It does the duplicate ensure for you.

For more information about [set](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, **removing duplicates** from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference. (For other containers see
>   the built-in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections
>   module.)

Try the following code to wait until the user entered 5 number:

```
numbers = set()
expected_number_count = 5
print('You must enter {0} different numbers.'.format(expected_number_count))
while len(numbers) < expected_number_count:
    numb=int(input('Please enter your number: '))
    numbers.add(numb)
```

Output:

```
Please enter your number: 1
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 2
Please enter your number: 3
Please enter your number: 4
Please enter your number: 5
>>> numbers
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

If you wish to *"punish"* the user for each time he entered a number for the seconds time you can try:

```
numbers = set()
expected_number_count = 5
print('You must enter {0} different numbers.'.format(expected_number_count))
while len(numbers) < expected_number_count:
    numb=int(input('Please enter your number: '))
    if numb in numbers:
        numbers.remove(numb)
    else:
        numbers.add(numb)
```

Comment: @Amiran thanks. But thats not exactly what I am asking. I  want to know what I can do so that my count is basically stopped and only restarts when the user enter a number that is not already there.

Comment: Let me get it straight, you wish to remove an element from the list if the user has already entered it before?
And wait until you have 5 different numbers?

Comment: @Amiran. Nice  one. sorry about the delay. you were on track